# In vbs how would I close out of the navigation window in Microsoft Word?

Tags: vba, vbscript

I have a script that goes though and sorts and removes tables that I don't need. I found that the script slows down to nothing when the Navigation window is open.
I have tried so much that It would take me a while to list. Google shows little hope.

EDIT: Here is a basic version of the code I'm using to sort through the tables. I tried to clean it up the junk as much as I can. The code works just fine for sorting the tables I just want to know how to close out of the Navigation window in WORD.

```
    For Each oTable In objDoc.Tables

    Table.innerHTML = "On Table " & Tablenum & " of " & TotalTables
    If oTable.Columns.Count = 2 Then
        oTable.Cell(1,1).Select
        Set rng = objSelection
        If objSelection.Information(wdWithInTable) Then
            If Instr(1,rng, "SRS_",1 ) > 0 Then
                For row = 0 to oTable.Rows.Count
                    rowcount = oTable.Rows.Count
                    Dim SrsTag
                    Dim deleteit
                    oTable.Cell(row,1).Select
                    Set rng = objSelection
                    If Instr(1,rng, "SRS_",1 ) > 0 Then
                        objSelection.Cells(1).Range.Select
                        strTag = objSelection
                        strTag = Replace(strTag," ","")
                        strTag = Replace(strTag,vbCr," ")
                        strTag = Replace(strTag,vbLf," ")
                        strTagarr = Split(strTag)
                        SrsTag = strTagarr(0)
                        If UBound(strTagarr) > 1 Then
                            deleteit = True
                            For airframe = 1 To UBound(strTagarr)
                                If Instr(1,strTagarr(airframe), Frame, 1 ) > 0 And len(strTag) > 1 And strTag <> " " Then
                                    deleteit = False
                                End If
                            Next
                        Else
                            deleteit = False
                        End If
                        If deleteit = True Then
                            objSelection.Rows.Delete
                            rowcount = rowcount - 1
                            If (rowcount = 0) Then
                                TableCount = TableCount - 1
                                Exit For
                            Else
                                row = row - 1
                            End If
                        Else
                            objSelection.TypeText(SrsTag)
                        End If
                    End If
                Next
            Else
                objSelection.Move
            End If
        End If
    End If
Next
```

Comment: can you show us your code?

Comment: Well the code has only to do with tables but ill see if I can simplify the main process of it.

Comment: Edited. I don't think it will help with the question however.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can add the

```
CommandBars("Navigation").Visible = False
```

Comment: Hmm it worked in a macro let me through it into the script and see what happends.

Comment: I tried objSelection.Application.CommandBars("Navigation").Visible = False and it game me a 'The server threw an exception"

Comment: @snhp -did u try the 
   objword.CommandBars("Navigation").Visible = False 'objword is the word application

Comment: Just did. It game me the same error. It works in a macro inside of word however.... hmmm.

Comment: you have to declare it after the you have set the word application Example: SET objWord = CreateObject("Word.Application") objWord.CommandBars("Navigation").Visible = true
I should work.I just now checked

Comment: kk I got it to work. I had objWord.Visible = False. I set it to true and now its working. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

ActiveWindow.DocumentMap = False